# parallel package - vertical alignment

Tags: sectioning, parallel

I'm trying to combine `parallel` package with `extbook` (or `book`) but I can't achieve the wanted layout.

```
\documentclass[
    17pt,
    twoside,
    openright
]{extbook}

\usepackage[Verbose]{parallel}

\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[p]{0pt}{0pt}
  \ParallelLText{\section{One}Hello\\123}
  \ParallelRText{\section{Two}Hello\\123\\345\\678}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the picture below, the content of the page is on the bottom, when I'm expecting to see everything on top.

Omitting the `\section` block the content is correctly aligned on top.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Try \raggedbottom (both columns).